# Why must we say 我可以从你那儿借钱吗？ instead of just 我可以从你借钱吗？

Tags: grammar

> <s>我可以从你借钱吗？</s>
> Can I borrow money from you?

At some point in our language learning journey, we learn that 从[person] is considered a grammar error in Chinese (despite the equivalent not being a grammar error in English), and we have to change it to 从[place]:

> 我可以从你**那儿**借钱吗？
> Can I borrow money from you there?

I'm wondering if there's any justification to this, beyond "that's just how it is" or "some stuffy linguist said so".

**Question**: Why must we say 我可以从你那儿借钱吗？ instead of just 我可以从你借钱吗？

Comment: Not a full answer, but an observation: It's tempting to use 從 (从) in Chinese as we would use "from" in English, but though there's a lot of overlap, they are clearly not identical. In Chinese, for these purposes, a person is not a place (and much less a time). Even if something were to issue from a person's body, we would (at least I would) generally say something like 從他身體(上).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why must we say 我可以从你那儿借钱吗？ instead of just 我可以从你借钱吗

- **从 somewhere** 借钱 --> borrow **from somewhere**
- **向 someone** 借钱 --> borrow **from someone**

你那儿 (your place) is somewhere, so we use 从 (I got the borrowed money **from your place**)

你(you) is someone, so we use 向 instead of 从 (I make a loan request **to you**)

Similarly:

- 從銀行那裡借钱 (O) (銀行那裡 is somewhere)
- 向銀行借钱 (O) (銀行 is someone)
- 從你借钱 (X) (你 is someone)
- 從銀行借钱 (O) (here, 銀行 referred to as somewhere the bank is located, not the bank itself as a company)

Notice:

In the sentence '我可以从你那儿借钱吗？' the one who lends you the money might not be the person you are talking to, he might just be an employee there in the bank. Meanwhile, 你 is the one who lends out the money in 我可向你借钱吗

Comment: While "向银行借钱" gives Google search 686,000 results, "从银行借钱" gives 438,000. I looked through the sources, they are both credible and quite formal.

Comment: 银行 in 向银行借钱 refers to the bank itself; "从银行借钱" actually means '银行那裡'  referring to the place where the bank is located

Comment: I agree, but this means that is particular form should best be accepted as correct.

Comment: 从银行借钱 is fine because 银行 can refer to as " a company(someone)" or "a place (somewhere)" ; But 你  cannot be referred to as a place

Comment: I’m not saying the case of 银行 can be generalized to 你. What I propose to be accepted as correct is 从银行借钱, which you considered incorrect in your original answer.

Comment: It makes sense, see my edition

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to ask "Can I borrow money from you?", the translation should be "我可以**向(和)**你借錢嗎?". The sentence "我可以从你那儿借錢吗?" is fine if your friend works for a lending company, which explains the phrase "从你那儿" (from the **place** you related to)

For private borrowing/lending, the sentence "我可以**向(和)**你借錢嗎?" is usually used. For formal (legal binding) borrowing/lending through a middleman (your friend), "我可以从你那儿借錢吗?" is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

从 as a preposition can be placed before a place, position, point of time, which means from.
In the sentence 从你那儿借钱,你那儿 can be seen as a place, so it works.
In spoken Chinese, we normally use 找 + somebody +借钱 instead. Two example:
我们找刘老师借钱。 We will borrow money from teacher Liu.
我们找她借钱。 We are going to borrow money from her.

Answer (score 0):

You can just say:

你可以借点钱给我吗？
Can you lend me some money?

I can't understand how 向 ，usually meaning 'to' suddenly undergoes a reversal to mean 'from'. That's very hard to explain.

我们要向雷锋学习。
我可以向你借钱吗？